# shorten the time for R CMD check pkg_name

Tags: r, package

I am developing an R package, and I have the following questions:

1. I use the roxygen2 package for the development, specifically I use roxygenize("pkg_Name") in R before running R CMD check pkg_Name in the shell mode. I found the time spent on checking the package so long, and wonder if there is any way to "cache" the unchanged results? I often made minor changes for my R functions being developed, and I don't wanna spend that long time for running R CMD check...

Thank you so much!

Comment: You have two questions here. Therefore I suggest you separate this into two questions. In other words, edit this question to remove 2) and then ask 2) as a new question.